# Exporting HTML Table to Excel Extension Issues

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

I am working on an existing page which exports a HTML table to Excel by building an excel document with the markup below. Whenever the new Excel document opens, however, I receive a warning saying that *"The file format and extension of 'ExcelDocName.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe."* I suspect this is happening because of the .xls extension, but simply changing xls to xlsx gives me a message stating *"Excel cannot open the file 'ExcelDocName.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid."* How should I edit this markup to eradicate these issues?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html  xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'> 
<head>  
   <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html;charset=windows-1252'><meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Excel 11'> 
   <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet> <meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Excel 11'> 
<style> 
<!--table @page{}-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>  <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>    <x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes> 
</x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--> 
</head>
<body><form method='POST' action='" &APSPostName&".asp' name='frmExcel'></form>    
    <!-- Table HTML goes here -->
</body></html>
```

The following is included after the markup is created.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="&ExcelName&".xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in my application. Just found out that this is an issue with **Microsoft Excel** and not the file itself, from **Excel 2007** on wards to the recent **Excel 2016**, it does not allow you to open **HTML content** using Excel **unless** it is saved with a **.html** extension.

Although if you save it with a **.xls extension** you can open the file with **Open Office** or **Libre Office** without any errors but you will receive errors opening with **Microsoft Excel (2007 - Current)**

I'm currently working with the following solutions to see what's best:

1. Save the file as **.html extension** and inform user to **open it with Microsoft Excel** (Once opened they can save it as an excel document).
2. Save the file with a **.xls extension** and inform user to **open it with Open Office or Libre Office.** to avoid the annoying error.
3. Save the file with a **.xls extension** and **inform the user about the error** and **inform them to ignore the error and click yes when it pops up.**

Maybe you can see what works best for you.

Let me know if you find any other way to work around the error.

**Link about the error**: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning-on-opening-excel-workbook-from-a-web-site-2/